# I would do / I would have done - What are the grammar terms of this tense/mood?

Tags: grammar, conjugation

Since my student days I’ve used abbreviations for the tenses. “I would do” is for me 
Conditional 1 (C1) and “I would have done” C2. And for me it is not important whether these verb forms are called tenses, moods or aspects.
I recently wanted to talk about these verbs forms and realized I can’t talk of C1 and C2 because these are only my private abbreviations.
I looked up the English names for these forms and found no standard terms. Instead these forms are awkwardly paraphrased.And when a survey of the tenses is given there are only six tenses, the *would*-forms are generally omitted.

Now my question:  Is there no standard term for these *would*-forms?

Comment: There are 12 verb tenses , how did you come up with six tenses ?

Comment: Actually you're very close: you just need to change your C1 to second conditional and C2 to third conditional (first conditional is "if A, i will do B", zero conditional: "if a, then B") [more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences)

Comment: Could someone explain the question to me?i would be grateful.

Comment: @msan -You are talking of sentences types with a clause of condition. I talk of tenses.

Comment: @Argot - I  don't count continous forms as real tenses, they a normal tenses of to be with a special complement. They are a pseudo- conjugation.

Comment: "First/second/third conditional" are, as I have gathered from this site, commonly used in teaching ESL. Previously they were unknown to me, though I have been reading fairly widely in Linguistics for forty years.

Comment: First/second/third/conditional are sentence types with a clause of condition and the terms are first-school-year terms. The would-forms alone should have a standard name and they should occur in a conjugation table.

Comment: This is not a tense/mood. This is a complex [verb phrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) starting with a modal auxiliary verb  (_would_), followed by the infinitive (V1) form of _have_, the auxiliary for the Perfect construction, followed by the  past participle (V3) of the next verb (e.g, _done_). So it's a modal perfective construction of some sort (other modals include _can, may, might, will, could, should, must_).

Comment: Future tense is also formed with a modal and I see nothing complex in will/would + infinitive. It's one of the simplest structures, just as "can do".

Answer (score 1):

Conditional Sentences:

1. Zero Conditional (facts - both parts in present tense): 
   If it rains, water falls from the sky
2. First Conditional (real possibilities - if+present, will+infinitive):
   It it rains, I will use my umbrella
3. Second Conditional (here we talk about the unlikely - if+past simple, would+infinitive):
   If it were to rain, I would have to buy an umbrella.
4. Third Conditional (same as 2nd but in the past - if+past perfect, would+perfect infinitive):
   If it had rained, I would have had to buy an umbrella
5. Mixed Conditional (mix of time from the above - tenses can be mixed)
   If it had not rained, I wouldn't be wet

(all the above can also have the progressive aspect)

Conditional mood is the would+verb part in second and third conditional.

Mood and aspect can be combined:

1. simple aspect: would do (simple conditional)
2. progressive aspect: would be doing (progressive conditional)
3. perfect aspect: would have done (perfect conditional)
4. perfect progressive aspect: would have been doing (perfect progressive conditional)

Comment: Tense/mood, to write "would + infinitive/infinitive perfect" is cumbersome. Why should a mood not have a name?

Comment: @rogermue see update

Comment: A perfect confusion: the same name for special sentence  types and as name for a special verb form. Not astonishing that learners have difficulties.